# Documents required to go to Alaska from Vancouver

Tags: visas

I am an Indian citizen having an Indian passport. I am planning to travel to Alaska from Vancouver via one way 7 night Norwegian cruise line. Do I need to carry any other document other than the US and Canada tourist visas?

Answer (score 3):

No, arriving on a ship is just like arriving by land. So no other docs required if you have visa, although you might want to have some of your financial, etc. docs on hand in case questioned by the officer.